# Automatic template function specialization on parameter value

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<bool encodeit, typename T>
std::string encap(const char* tag,T s,alignT alignement=alignDisable,bool encodeit=false){
```

I would like to specialize automatically the above function definition based on the function argument passed. 
Why doesn't it works ? ( shouldn't it be nice to have it work ? ).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What are you trying to do? What didn't work about it?

Comment: Are you sure you want both a template argument `encodeit` and a function argument with the same name?

Comment: I need to pass the parameters to the function and have 2 different versions compiled one for encodeit=true and one for encodeit=false ( and many depending on T ), but instead of using it like encap<true> and encap<false> I would like the compiler to select based on the constant parameter passed to the function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I need it to be the same argument ( as the same is the T used )

Comment: function argument is for runtime, template argument is for compile time.

Comment: When the function argument is always a constant it could be resolved any way (theoretically)

Comment: And particularly for `bool`, if it is known at compile time and want 2 different version, just create 2 different methods and get rid of this `bool`: `encap_with_encode` and `encap_without_encode`.

Comment: @Jarod42 After all the mess, I am going that way ( duplicating some code by hand ).

Answer (score 0):

This can only work if `encodeIt` is a compile-time constant. If so, you can use tag dispatching:

```
template<typename T>
std::string encap(const char* tag, T s, std::true_type encode,
//                                  tag ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  alignT alignment=alignDisable) {
    //true version
}


template<typename T>
std::string encap(const char* tag, T s, std::false_type encode,
//                                  tag ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  alignT alignment=alignDisable) {
    //false version
}
```

Then you just call like this:

```
encap(tag, s, std::true_type{}); //calls true version
encap(tag, s, std::false_type{}); //calls false version

//calls true or false version depending on should_encode
encap(tag, s, std::integral_constant<bool, should_encode>{});
```

If you want to tidy up the calls a bit, you could wrap the tag dispatching, as suggested by n.m.:

```
template <bool Encode, typename T>
std::string encap(const char* tag, T s, alignT alignment=alignDisable)
{
    return encap(tag, s, std::integral_constant<bool, Encode>, alignment);
}
```

Then you would call like this:

```
encap<true>(tag, s); //calls true version
encap<false>(tag, s); //calls false version

//calls true or false version depending on should_encode
encap<should_encode>(tag, s);
```

Comment: `encap(tag, s, std::integral_constant<bool, should_encode>{});` vs `encap<false>(tag, s)`, who wins?

Comment: @n.m. Well the first one is possible and the second relies on partial function template specialization, which isn't in the language. So the first one wins.

Comment: "partial function template specialization" nope, none in sight.

Comment: You could make it shorter like `encap(tag, s, bool_c<should_encode>)`.

Comment: @n.m. If they want to have separate versions for `true` and `false` which work regardless of `T`, they'd need partial function specialization. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @n.m. No, because you can use tag dispatching, like in my answer.

Comment: Oops, yes, but if they want seoarate versions for true and false, they can use tag dispatching *from within* `encap<bool, T>` and skip the clutter at caller sites. (But there"s no sign they want it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what benefit you have by passing "true" (or) "false" as a template specialization (or) as function parameter.

But you can use it like this.. instead of defining a variable if your specilization has it already

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool encode, class T>                                                                                                                                                                                                                
void hello(T data)
{
   if (encode)
   {   
      std::cout << "encode is trus" << std::endl;
   }   
   std::cout << "Data is " << data << std::endl;

}

int main()
{
   hello<true,int>(5);
   hello<false,int>(6);
}
```

Comment: When used with some T the bool is always false so it is used as true only for some T. But the code doesn't compiles on all cases because there aren't all the versions of a function (for the case of encodeit=true) for all T. Instead by doing it at compile time I will avoid that.